# Removing duplicate rows based on date column and status

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table, where every row represents a change in the user's status and the occurrence date.

| Date | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2021 | 64 | Register |
| 02.04.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 02.07.2021 | 64 | Not Active |
| 02.10.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 02.25.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 02.30.2021 | 64 | Not Active |
| 03.03.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 01.01.2021 | 11 | Register |
| 01.06.2021 | 11 | Active |
| 01.07.2021 | 11 | Active |
| 01.10.2021 | 11 | Elite |
| 01.15.2021 | 11 | Elite |

It contains duplicate statues for different dates and I would like to retrieve only the latest status for when there are consequent statuses.

I want my end table to look like this:

| Date | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2021 | 64 | Register |
| 02.04.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 02.07.2021 | 64 | Not Active |
| 02.25.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 02.30.2021 | 64 | Not Active |
| 03.03.2021 | 64 | Active |
| 01.01.2021 | 11 | Register |
| 01.07.2021 | 11 | Active |
| 01.15.2021 | 11 | Elite |

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This looks like a gaps and island "Select Top 1 in group" problem.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD` to check if the next row is different, and exclude it if it's the same

```sql
SELECT
  Date,
  ID,
  Status
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Prev = LEAD(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE Prev <> Status OR Prev IS NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9a48fa97370a8e7d9723d9049e52172)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a "Gaps and Islands" problem as stated by a comment.

```
--SampleData
WITH mydata AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
 (1,'active',CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS Date))
,(1,'active',CAST(GETDATE()-2 AS Date))
,(1,'disabled',CAST(GETDATE()-3 AS Date))
,(1,'active',CAST(GETDATE()-4 AS Date))
,(1,'active',CAST(GETDATE()-5 AS Date))
,(2,'active',CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS Date))
,(2,'disabled',CAST(GETDATE()-2 AS Date))
,(2,'disabled',CAST(GETDATE()-3 AS Date))
,(2,'disabled',CAST(GETDATE()-4 AS Date))
,(2,'active',CAST(GETDATE()-5 AS Date))
) x(ID,Status,Date)
)
--Actual logic starts
,Islands AS (
SELECT *,
Island = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id, Date) -
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, Status ORDER BY Id, Date)
FROM mydata
)

SELECT Id, Status, Island, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
FROM Islands
GROUP BY Id, Status, Island
ORDER BY Id, MaxDate
```

In order to understand it, you will need to have a look at what Windowing functions are, and how they behave in this specific context.

The idea is to use scoped counters, one scoped by `Id`, the second by `Id, Status`.
The first one grows constantly and resets only when the `Id` changes, the second one resets also when the status is different.
By subtracting the two counters a "step" is created, and a new step is created every time the status changes while it remains constant if the status stays the same.
This "Step", called `Island` in the query can then be used to obtain the result you asked for.